# How to handle classes with different properties but same meanings?

Tags: c#

I have a lot of classes that represent a Person, like:

```
public class Person1 {
   public string Name {set;get;}
   public string FamilyName {set;get;}
   public string Patronymic {set;get;}
}

public class Person2 {
   public string FirstName {set;get;}
   public string SurName {set;get;}
   public string Patronymic {set;get;}
}

public class Person3 {
   public string PersonName {set;get;}
   public string Surname {set;get;}
   public string Patr {set;get;}
}

etc..
```

Now I want to combine fields and get `fullname = FamilyName + " " + Name + " " + Patronymic;`, but I want to do it in the  same code.
I see two ways to do it.

1. Make helper class with method:

```
public class PersonHelper
{
  public string GetFullName(string familyName, sting name, string patronymic) 
  {
     return FamilyName + " " + Name + " " + Patronymic;
  }
}
```

2. Use interface and make realisation of `GetFullName` in each class:

```
interface IFullNamed
{
   string GetFullName()
}

public class Person1: IFullNamed{
   public string Name {set;get;}
   public string FamilyName {set;get;}
   public string Patronymic {set;get;}

  string FullName(){
     return FamilyName + " " + Name + " " + Patronymic;
  }
}

public class Person2:IFullNamed{
   public string FirstName {set;get;}
   public string SurName {set;get;}
   public string Patronymic {set;get;}

   string FullName(){
     return SurName + " " + FirstName + " " + Patronymic;
   }
}
```

What way is correct or both wrong?

Comment: The question looks like `Opinion-based` but I select 2nd :)

Comment: How do you cope with `Charles de Batz de Castelmore d'Artagnan`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, as an option you can create an extension method to get the full name

Comment: I'll prefer interface approach.

Comment: your classes seem to violate DRY principle..

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Problem of separation fullnames to 3 meaning fields it is problem of goverment.

Comment: Why do you have all these classes in the first place? You should have a single class representing a single entity, not many classes representing the same thing.

Comment: your interface method is doing one thing only. concat of three properties..

Comment: @ZoharPeled maybe these are model classes from deserialization or something

Comment: @ZoharPeled It is jsut xsd.exe output.

Comment: Use the interface to `GetFullName` is the better way.

Comment: @KliverMax you can just override `ToString()`

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the approach with helper method and create an extension method to build a full name for every person

```cs
public static class Ext
{
    public static string GetFullName(this Person1 person)
    {
        return $"{person.FamilyName} {person.Name} {person.Patronymic}";
    }

    public static string GetFullName(this Person2 person)
    {
        return $"{person.SurName} {person.FirstName} {person.Patronymic}";
    }
}
```

Since [`string`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) class  is immutable in C#, it's better to use string interpolation or [`string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8) method rather then concatenate them (to avoid an additional allocation of strings).

But in terms of basic architecture principles make sense to create a base class or interface to encapsulate the fields, identifying a `Person` entity

```cs
public class Person 
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string FamilyName { set; get; }
    public string Patronymic { set; get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{FamilyName} {Name} {Patronymic}";
    }
}
```

If making a single entity isn't an option here, you can just override `ToString()` method to encapsulate a logic of getting a full name.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
interface IFullNamed
{
    string GetFullName();
}

public abstract class Person : IFullNamed
{
    public virtual string Name { set; get; }
    public virtual string FamilyName { set; get; }
    public virtual string Patronymic { set; get; }

    string IFullNamed.GetFullName()
    {
        return $"{FamilyName} {Name} {Patronymic}";
    }
}

public class Person1 : Person
{
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public override string Name { set; get; }
    [DisplayName("SurName")]
    public override string FamilyName { set; get; }
}

public class Person2 : Person
{
    [DisplayName("PersonName")]
    public override string Name { set; get; }
    [DisplayName("Surname")]
    public override string FamilyName { set; get; }
    [DisplayName("Patr")]
    public override string Patronymic { set; get; }
}

public class Person3 : Person
{
    [DisplayName("PersonName")]
    public override string Name { set; get; }
    [DisplayName("Surname")]
    public override string FamilyName { set; get; }
    [DisplayName("Patr")]
    public override string Patronymic { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your trouble is mount of properties in each classes are different.

You can create class `PersonHelper` and write `GetFullname` method use `params string[]` in `args`:

In this method, you can:

> Pass mount of args you want

```
// You can pass many arguments you want here
string fullNameOfPerson3 = PersonHelper.GetFullName(person3.FirstName, person3.SurName, person3.Patronymic);

// And get them by using this method
string GetFullName(params string[] args)
```

Full method:

```
    public static class PersonHelper
    {
        public static string GetFullName(params string[] args)
        {
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                result += i == args.Length - 1 ? args[i] : args[i] + " ";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

**Full code:** (this is only a very simple example. Try the way with your project)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ArrayFromTextFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person1 person1 = new Person1();
            Person2 person2 = new Person2();
            Person2 person3 = new Person2();

            string fullNameOfPerson1 = PersonHelper.GetFullName(person1.Name, person1.FamilyName, person1.Patronymic);
            string fullNameOfPerson2 = PersonHelper.GetFullName(person2.FirstName, person2.SurName, person2.Patronymic);
            string fullNameOfPerson3 = PersonHelper.GetFullName(person3.FirstName, person3.SurName, person3.Patronymic);

        }
    }

    public static class PersonHelper
    {
        public static string GetFullName(params string[] args)
        {
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                result += i == args.Length - 1 ? args[i] : args[i] + " ";
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    public class Person1
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public string FamilyName { set; get; }
        public string Patronymic { set; get; }
    }

    public class Person2
    {
        public string FirstName { set; get; }
        public string SurName { set; get; }
        public string Patronymic { set; get; }
    }

    public class Person3
    {
        public string PersonName { set; get; }
        public string Surname { set; get; }
        public string Patr { set; get; }
    }
}
```